# Problem in using functions Exec, passthru, System

Tags: php, system, exec, passthru

Hi all dear friends and teachers ... Heart

In the design phase of my current project I'm wrong and I tried Game, unfortunately I missed a positive result.
HuhHuh
Project in the programming language I've been using AutoHotKey Autoit or better to say, and convert source files to exe. (File for each user) to use Windows, I'm the Host or the PSP!...

When I had her by the php functions in this case, (Exec, passthru, System) implementation of the Wine and the file will run the compiler, the functions do not work! Functions passthru, System because their output, their output is 127, which was beaten off with that. I just ordered some of Linux I want to run PHP, which I still have to deal with the output 127.

Maybe I got the usual functions, these functions have been disabled, but when I saw my php.ini file, inside the disabled_fuctions There was no function!

However, I must say that PHP can not run the same command can be run properly by the SSH files and exe. Both are produced. Confused

The friends that I have experienced this please help ...

```
<?php
passthru('/usr/bin/wine /home/adslgpfo/public_html/iwe/Ahk2Exe.exe "/in a.ahk" ', $p);
print_r($p);

echo " - ";

system('wine /home/adslgpfo/public_html/iwe/Ahk2Exe.exe /in b.ahk ', $s);
print_r($s);
?>
```

Comment: Look into the `error.log` for possible explanations. - Also should your PHP have `safe_mode` enabled (see your phpinfo page) then the exec functions are disabled too.

Comment: Maybe I got the usual functions, these functions have been disabled, but when I saw my php.ini file, inside the disabled_fuctions There was no function!

Comment: `safe_mode` is enabled !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the PHP [`safe_mode`](http://php.net/safe_mode) is enabled, then the exec functions are disabled implicitly:

http://php.net/manual/features.safe-mode.functions.php

You will have to disabled that, or do some cumbersome workarounds with the `safe_mode_exec_dir` to allow `wine` to be executed.